# Using session.get() to retrieve content from web page

Tags: python, html, session, url, web-scraping

I'm attempting to scrape listings from Autotrader.com using the following code:

```
import requests
session = requests.Session()
url = 'https://www.autotrader.com/cars-for-sale/Burlingame+CA-94010?searchRadius=10&zip=94010&marketExtension=include&isNewSearch=true&sortBy=relevance&numRecords=25&firstRecord=0'
homepage = session.get(url)
```

It looks like the connection was successfully established:

```
In[115]: homepage
Out[115]: <Response [200]>
```

However, accessing the homepage content shows an error message and nothing resembling the content accessible via browser:

```
In[121]: homepage.content
Out[121]: 
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xml:lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Autotrader - page unavailable</title>

(...)

<h1>We're sorry for any inconvenience, but the site is currently unavailable.</h1>

(...)
```

I've tried adding a different user agent in headers using [user_agent](http://t.ly/znm83):

```
headers = {'User-Agent': generate_user_agent()}
homepage = session.get(url, headers=headers)
```

But get the same result: `page unavailable`

I also tried pointing to a security certificate (the root one?) that I downloaded from Chrome:

```
certificate = './certificate/root.cer'
homepage = session.get(url, headers=headers, verify=certificate)
```

but I see the error:

```
  File "/Users/michaelboles/Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/_util.py", line 54, in exception_from_error_queue
    raise exception_type(errors)

Error: [('x509 certificate routines', 'X509_load_cert_crl_file', 'no certificate or crl found')]
```

So I may not be doing that last part correctly.

Can anyone offer any help on **retrieving Autotrader webpage content** as it is displayed in the browser?

Comment: It looks like that site loads content dynamically, in which case you would need browser automation like selenium since the page isn't loaded fully until it's actually visited by a browser. It's also possible that they're just identifying you as a bot and blocking the page content based on that, but you seem to have tried the most common fixes for that

Comment: Tried the url and get message `We're sorry for any inconvenience, but the site is currently unavailable.`

Comment: @Sers: Weird -- when I paste this URL in to my browser it loads the page normally: ```https://www.autotrader.com/cars-for-sale/Burlingame+CA-94010?searchRadius=10&zip=94010&marketExtension=include&isNewSearch=true&sortBy=relevance&numRecords=25&firstRecord=0```

Comment: @G. Anderson: Thanks. If this is indeed the case, could you point me to a good reference for scraping dynamic content with Selenium?

Comment: Again, not totally sure this is your issue, but if it is, the best place to start would be [the selenium docs](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what `User-Agent` this `user_agent` module generates, but when I run:

```
import requests

url = 'https://www.autotrader.com/cars-for-sale/Burlingame+CA-94010?searchRadius=10&zip=94010&marketExtension=include&isNewSearch=true&sortBy=relevance&numRecords=25&firstRecord=0'

headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:72.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/72.0'} # <-- try this header

print( requests.get(url, headers=headers).text )
```

I get normal page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><script>
window.NREUM||(NREUM={}),__nr_require=function(t,n,e){function r(e){if(!n[e]){var o=n[e]={exports:{}};t[e][0].call(o.exports,function(n){var o=t[e][1][n];return r(o||n)},o,o.exports)}return n[e].exports}if("function"==typeof __nr_require)return __nr_require;for(var o=0;o<e.length;o++)r(e[o]);return r}({1:[function(t,n,e){function r(t){try{s.console&&console.log(t)}catch(n){}}var o,i=t("ee"),a=t(15),s={};try{o=localStorage.getItem("__nr_flags").split(","),console&&"function"==typeof console.log&&(s.console=!0,o.indexOf("dev")!==-1&&(s.dev=!0),o.indexOf("nr_dev")!==-1&&(s.nrDev=!0))}catch(c){}s.nrDev&&i.on("internal-error",func
...
```

Comment: You're right -- this seems to work! I don't fully understand why this ```User-Agent``` is special, but I appreciate the solution. Thanks